# Make a key be pressed with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I have a DOM element in my frame, and when I click on it, I want to simulate a ESCAPE  key press (so I cannot use keydown or keyup, because its the click that generates it)

Is it possible?

Comment: Follow link :)...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What should receive and react to that `esc` keypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
e = jQuery.Event("keydown"); 
e.which = 27; //27 = ESC
$("youelement").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the [jquery trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) can be used with jQuery.Event object with type as keypress